# how to extract a value from json string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a source table as like below

[image]

on top this table there is a business logic implemented as like below

```
select id, TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name,salary,deptno))) as d_list 
from `project.dataset.sample_tab` 
group by 1
```

Now after applying business logic the table look like below

[image]

From the above table i want to extract only salary column data for additional calculations. how we can extract ? please suggest me

I tried `JSON_EXTRACT(d_list,"$.salary")` but it is giving me null values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select id, json_extract(trim(d_list, '[]'),"$.salary") salary
from (
  select id, TO_JSON_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name,salary,deptno))) as d_list 
  from `project.dataset.sample_tab` 
  group by 1
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]